# How to use maplibre-gl with react-map-gl

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-map-gl, maplibre-gl

I am currently taking my first steps in using [maplibre](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/api/) together with react-map-gl.

I have read the [documentation](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/get-started/get-started#using-with-a-mapbox-gl-fork) about how to use a fork of mapbox.

I have adapted `webpack-config`. I use a [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) project with [rewind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired). This is my config-overrides.js.

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    //do stuff with the webpack config...
    module.exports = {
        webpack: (config) => {
            config.module.rules.push({
                resolve:{
                    alias: {
                        ...config.resolve.alias,
                        'mapbox-gl': 'maplibre-gl'
                    }
                }
            })
          // Important: return the modified config
          return config
        },
      }
    return config;
  }
```

With the following  code I see the map from Maptiler  a few seconds, which is loaded via maplibre.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

export const Map = () => {
  const [mapViewport, setMapViewport] = useState({
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100wh",
    longitude: 2.571606,
    latitude: 45.226913,
    zoom: 5
  });

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...mapViewport}
      //mapboxApiAccessToken="MapboxToken"
      mapStyle= 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/style.json?key=MaptilerToken'
      onViewportChange={setMapViewport}
    ></ReactMapGL>
  );
};
```

Then it disappears and I see this error message in the console of my browser.

```
Error: A valid Mapbox access token is required to use Mapbox GL JS. To create an account or a new access token, visit https://account.mapbox.com/
```

If I use the line  `mapboxApiAccessToken="MapboxToken"`, I can use the maptiler map without a problem.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

export const Map = () => {
  const [mapViewport, setMapViewport] = useState({
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100wh",
    longitude: 2.571606,
    latitude: 45.226913,
    zoom: 5
  });

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...mapViewport}
      mapboxApiAccessToken="MapboxToken"
      mapStyle= 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/style.json?key=MaptilerToken'
      onViewportChange={setMapViewport}
    ></ReactMapGL>
  );
};
```

But I don't want to need a mapbox token any more.
What am I missing ?

I asked this question [here](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/discussions/1482) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The override was the problem.  The config-overrides.js should look like this

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        resolve:{
            alias: {
                ...config.resolve.alias,
                'mapbox-gl': 'maplibre-gl'
            }
        }
    })

    return config
}
```

Comment: `resolve` doesn't belong to `config.module.rules`, it's a top level prop.